# semantic-tag-folding mode in CEDET

Tags: emacs, cedet

I want to fold the code, and I know the CEDET could help me do this. But the semantic-tag-folding mode is not a part of the CEDET shipped with Emacs 24.3.1. So what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install it from here http://cedet.sourceforge.net/git-repo.shtml
and add such lines to `.emacs`:

```
(setq cedet-root-path (file-name-as-directory "~/projects/cedet/"))
(load-file (concat cedet-root-path "cedet-devel-load.el"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat cedet-root-path "contrib"))
(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list "~/projects/cedet/doc/info")
```

and my emacs stop using `cedet` that part of it. Note this is only switch external cedet, to proper configure need you need more `elisp` code,
but this is not related to question.

Comment: That's the answer. But I prefer to use the hs-minor-mode now, there is still other problems when using semantic-tag-folding method.